# Trying to get property of non-object [laravel 5.2]

Tags: laravel

I'm getting trouble in getting the data from foreign key .
already make relation between 2 tables, but still error gave me this "Trying to get property of non-object"

this is my models

```
public function tourism()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Tourism','tourism_id');
}
```

this is my controller

```
 $ratings = Ratings::orderBy('rating','desc')->get();
    $ratings = $ratings->take(6);
```

and this is my blade

```
<tbody>
 @if($ratings)
      @foreach($ratings as $data)
            <tr>
                 <td class="center">{{$data->id}}</td>
                 <td class="center">{{$data->tourism_id->nama}}</td>
                 <td class="center">{{$data->rating}}</td>
            </tr>
@endforeach
 @endif
</tbody>
```

thanks

Comment: show the full method can you please? do you have  `return View('whatever')->with('ratings',$ratings);` in your controller method?

Comment: Do you have data in your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<td class="center">{{$data->tourism->nama}}</td>
```

**EDIT**

This situation occurs when you trying get `nama` property.
But `tourism_id` it's just an integer, am I right?
First of all,for accessing related model you should use you relationship method(`tourism`) instead of FK field(`tourism_id`).
Then you should check are there any related model in `tourims()` or not. For this purpose i recommend you use ternary operator, so your line should be something like:

```
<td class="center">{{$data->tourism->first() ? $data->tourism->first()->nama : 'No tourism'}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have this controller and the model relationship as above:

```
function ratingsView() {

 $ratings = Ratings::orderBy('rating','desc')->get();
 $ratings = $ratings->take(6);

 return View('rating')->with('ratings',$ratings);

}
```

In your views,

```
<tbody>
 @if($ratings)
      @foreach($ratings as $data)
            <tr>
                 <td class="center">{{$data->id}}</td>
                 <td class="center">{{$data->tourism()->first()->nama}}</td>
                 <td class="center">{{$data->rating}}</td>
            </tr>
@endforeach
 @endif
</tbody>
```

Make sure your `rating` table have `id`, `rating` as well as `tourism_id` attributes and your tourism table have `name` attribute as well as of course there is data in both tables.

You definitely need to check the the availability of the data and handle it accordingly. But that is different issue

Comment: why `->tourism_id()->first()`?  `$data->tourism->nama` will work fine i guess its a belongsto

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja Belongs to will return BelongsTo class. We need to fetch the data using first method

Comment: This solution occurs the same problem if will be no related models.

Comment: @huuuk You are right. But this is assuming there is data. The main issue of this question is not about the availability of the data but because of wrong usage of model relationship

Comment: have you tried   `$ratings = Ratings::with('tourism)->orderBy('rating','desc')->take(6)->get();` can you dump the result and show us the out put?

Answer (score 0):

in your controller use it like this:

```
$ratings = Ratings::orderBy('rating','desc')->take(6)->get();
```